Do I need to return anything important from the switch cases or is just having it like this enough to differentiate different PHP?
I'm trying to create an admin page and below is my code for it and its multiple panels, wherein clicking the respective images will result in changing the replaceThis div to its respective php file content.
<div class="left-container">
    <img src="" id="Dashboard" alt="Dashboard">
    <img src="" id="ManUse" alt="Manage Users">
    <img src="" id="ManFile" alt="Manage Files">
    <img src="" id="FfApprove" alt="Files for Approval">
</div>
<div class="right-container" id="replaceThis">

    <?php 
        switch($_SESSION['admain']){
            case 'Dashboard':
                         
            break;
            case 'ManUse':
                           
            break;
            case 'ManFile':
                            
            break;
            case 'FfApprove':

            break;
        }
    ?>
</div>

This is my javascript code so far, and the contents of the respective PHP files are currently empty because I don't know if I need to print a function or just call the entire php file (I don't know how to do this yet) or should I incorporate the `$_SESSION['admain'] into the php file.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Dashboard").click(function() {
    let selID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#replaceThis").load(".modular/dasbord.php", {
      newDis : selID
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ManUse").click(function() {
    let selID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#replaceThis").load(".modular/manuser.php", {
      newDis : selID
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ManFile").click(function() {
    let selID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#replaceThis").load(".modular/manfile.php", {
      newDis : selID
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FfApprove").click(function() {
    let selID = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#replaceThis").load(".modular/forapprove.php", {
      newDis : selID
    });
  });
});


I updated my code to test if a string is passed and use the element id if not

Thanks for this, @mplungjan. Still struggling a bit when it comes to full stack development so I really appreciate the help.

You need to be DRY (don't repeat yourself) and have just one php return stuff.
The switch does not belong in the index.php but in the replacethis.php
You MAY want to wrap the images in a link (and change 'img' to 'a' in the on click, to add more accessibility to the page. When you do, remember to cancel the link with event.preventDefault.
Also make sure to spell everything correctly


$(function() { // when page elements are available
  function loadPage(id) {
    let selID = typeof id === "string" ? id : $(this).attr('id'); // if passed an ID use it
    console.log(selID);
    $("#replaceThis").load(".modular/replacethis.php", {
      newDis: selID
    });
  }

  const $nav = $(".left-container")
    .on("click", 'img', loadPage); // any click on an image
  loadPage($nav.find('img').eq(0).prop('id')); // initialise
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-container">
  <img src="" id="Dashboard" alt="Dashboard">
  <img src="" id="ManUse" alt="Manage Users">
  <img src="" id="ManFile" alt="Manage Files">
  <img src="" id="FfApprove" alt="Files for Approval">
</div>
<div class="right-container" id="replaceThis"></div>



then replacethis.php can have
<?php 
    switch($_POST['newDis']){
        case 'Dashboard':
          echo file_get_contents('dashboard.html');
          break;
        case 'ManUse':
          echo file_get_contents('manuse.html');                         
          break;
        case 'ManFile':
          echo file_get_contents('manfile.html');                          
          break;
        case 'FfApprove':
          echo file_get_contents('ffapprove.html');
          break;
    }
?>


Hi, is there a reason why file_get_contents won't output my php file? I found out include works and I added it to my code by adding the include replaceThis.php inside the right-container div. Same with my replaceThis.php, I replaced the file_get_contents to include because it says no directory exists but when I use include it outputs the file with the same directory path.

Turn on the PHP error handler - - read the documentation - perhaps the files are not where you think they are

found the issue, there was a missing / on the load function. But now the issue is it defaults to dashboard instead of the initialized value of the $_SESSION['admain'] and also keeps on overwriting the div even after clicking the img element.

After checking php debugging mode, it apparently closes everything and reloads the php page where the replaceThis div is located.

Nevermind, I fixed it by converting the code to Ajax. Complicated but really helpful

Ajax is a recommended way.
